# Place HTML-tags into WordPress page using dashboard

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, dashboard

I try to put this HTML into my page content using dashboard:

```
<div>
     <p class="text-center">
         <a class="btn btn-large btn-light" title="Kontakt" href="/?page_id=20">Kontakt <i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>

         <a class="btn btn-large btn-light" title="Standorte &amp; Informationen" href="/?page_id=20">Standorte &amp;
             Informationen <i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
     </p>
</div>
```

But here is the HTMl what I getting on page:

```
<div>
    <p class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-light" title="Kontakt" href="/?page_id=20">Kontakt <i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-light" title="Standorte &amp; Informationen" href="/?page_id=20">Standorte &amp;<br />
        Informationen <i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

See the difference? So why it genereates two `<p>`, and first has the class what I assing? Maybe it my mistake and I didnt get something with WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) might be active and insert the second `p` if you have a double line-break in the code you enter.

Try removing the empty line between the two `a`-elements and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with Wordpress default formating filter

Place this in your functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: 8 seconds faster. :-P

Comment: I had to get the codex link... well... erm... whatever. ;-)